# How can i apply SMOTE for multiclass text data

Tags: python, oversampling

I have a Multiclass dataset for which i want to use SMOTE, but i am facing an

> ValueError: "sampling_strategy" can be a float only when the type of
> target is binary. For multi-class, use a dict.

I want to balance my data using SMOTE or any other technique for multi class and my raw data is in text.

---

Added data to understand
If there is a file called my_data, this has 5 categories: car,bike,bicycle,bus and pedestrian.

Where there are 56 data records for car category,18 data records in bus category, 11 data records in bike category, 10 data records in bicycle category and 5 data records in pedestrian category

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the details. Do not use comments to clarify. Code in comments is unreadable, and comments may or may not be shown initially. Make it easy for people to help you. Make sure your code is a [mcve]. What happens when you run your code? What do you expect to happen instead? Include any errors you may get. You may also want to read [ask].

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you. Did you solve it ?  If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: This may give you ideas: https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-imbalanced-classification/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the datatype that you are passing.
[Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/master/imblearn/utils/_validation.py#L355) is the official documentation and you will find all the possible values.

Comment: so, do i need to featurize the text data and then split into train and test?

Answer (score 0):

so if you are working with python and pandas simply do this get read your csv file into pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')
# get a count of the target class
df['target'].value_counts()
```

since car has 56 data records, and the rest has much lower number of data records, you can upscale the data records of the other four categories(bike,bus,pedestrian) to match the number of data records of the car category.
Extract the data records of car category

```
car  = df[(df.target == "car") ]
car
```

Then Extract the data records of bike category

```
bike  = df[(df.target == "bike") ]
bike
```

```
bike_and_car=car
#merge the bike and car dataframes
bike_and_car = bike_and_car.append(bike, ignore_index = True)
bike_and_car
bike_and_car = bike_and_car.replace('car',1)
bike_and_car = bike_and_car.replace('bike',0)
```

```
X=bike_and_car.drop(['target'], axis=1)
y=bike_and_car['target]
```

Now import the smote module SMOTENC or SVMSMOTE from imblearn library

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTENC
smote_nc = SMOTENC(random_state=42)
X_res, y_res = smote_nc.fit_resample(X, y)
X_res
```

`X_res` should contain additional generated synthetic data records to the  original data you initially had for the bike category repeat the same procedure for other categories: bicycle and pedestrian

You can downlaod that dataframe `X_res` as a csv

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Moon\Documents\my_data_with_synthetic_data.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If using SMOTE is not mandatory, I'd try CTGAN which handles categorical features and can generate new synthetic without this need to manipulate the data. You can explore a solution with [ydata-synthetic](https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-synthetic) for instance, and if you have a .csv, you can simply try it out with the streamlit app, which is super intuitive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).